# Autocalibration of any pose - openni_tracker

Tags: calibration, kinect, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to edit the openni_tracker.cpp program to enable auto calibration without requiring the user to present a certain pose? Typically the program requires the user to be in a PSI pose.

NeedPoseForCalibration() returns TRUE in my case. If we can make it return FALSE, then we can auto-calibrate it. How do we set it to FALSE?

IS there some other work-around to enable automatic calibration as soon as a user enters the field of view of the kinect camera, i.e., as soon as the User is detected?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32373/autocalibration-of-any-pose---openni_tracker/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2012-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Around 2012 the package openni_tracker indeed needed the user to do the PSI pose.
The latest version (and since quite a long time actually) does the calibration automatically.

---

Originally posted by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) with karma: 157 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0